# How to pass a specific object to a fragment (thymelaf)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem that i would like to get help with!

I am using Intellij Idea and are using Spring MVC with Thymeleaf. I have created a fragment and all is fine and dandy, it works good and gets imported in my current html file.

```
<div th:replace="fragments/ModalCart :: modal(${products.get(0)})"></div>
```

This is my import statment and as you can see i am passing a single object of type `Product`.

This is my fragment html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="modal(product)">
    <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <section class="card">
                <div class="columns">
                    <div class="column">
                        <p th:text="${product.getImgUrl()}"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that my 'product' in the modal fragment is of type `Object` not type `Product` as i would like to to be (because of that if i call the `imgUrl` getter method on the passed in product i get a red underline that tells me it can not be resolved, even doe it works i have a error in my html file which is annoying).
How would i make sure that the parameter that gets pass into this class is of type `Product` class and not of `java.lang.Object` class?

Is there any way to cast it back to a `Product` or am I stuck?

Thanks

Comment: Variables are provided to a template with `org.springframework.ui.Model` which is a `String` to `Object` store. I guess once you add your variable to model its type becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thymeleaf doesn't actually care about the type of the variable passed to the fragment, so `${product.getImgUrl()}` (equivalent to `${product.imgUrl}`) should work whether or not it has red underlines.

As for fixing those problems... this is IDE specific. For example, in Intellij I think something like this should work:

```
<div th:fragment="modal(product)">
  <!--/*@thymesVar id="product" type="your.package.Product"*/-->
```

Where you replace `your.package.Product` with your actual package.

Comment: Excellent Answer! In my Intellij IDEA 2021.2, The comment line must be put on top of `th:fragment` line. And the /* */ comment pattern in the xml comment is not much necessary.

Comment: @RickoD I think the `/* ... */` part make it a thymeleaf comment which don't get output in the HTML (otherwise you risk exposing objects names -- if that matters).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I placed the fragment in a separate file that doesn't appear as a page, and placed the comment outside (above) the fragment element so I didn't notice it when I referenced it